# Android: How to change webview width before capturePicture to save the view

Tags: android, image, canvas, webview, bitmap

The webview on my application becomes quite long. I want the user to be able to save the webview as image to enable sharing.
It is working right now but the code generates a long image. I want make the height\width propotional before saving e.g. 800\600 etc.

Not sure how to do it??

This is how I am saving the jpg:

```
Picture picture = webview.capturePicture();
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
picture.draw(c);
FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
    File file = new File(pathName);
    file.createNewFile();
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (fos != null) {
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

and the layout is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/a_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/reload"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/reload" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_above="@id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Someone answered earlier about scaling the bitmap to solve this. That answer has now been deleted, don't know why. But i don't think that would be the solution. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Is the capturePicture() API working for you with all the URLs? Its only working for few URLs for me (eg: eBay) and not for some (eg: BBC). Any ideas? My code is similar to yours but I'm not writing the bitmap to a file and just using the bitmap for thumbnails.